# The \"path\" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or URL. Received undefined" error when uploading Multiple file using formidable

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-s3, file-upload, formidable

I am trying to upload files to aws s3 using formidable . its working fine for single file but when i go with multiple files its showing error The "path" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or URL. Received undefined" in postman

```
exports.addProduct = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const form = formidable({
    multiples: true,
    keepExtensions: true,
  });

  form.parse(req, async function (err, fields, files) {
    try {
      if (err) {
        throw new CustomError(err.message || "Something went wrong", 500);
      }

      let productId = new Mongoose.Types.ObjectId().toHexString();
    
      // check for fields
      if (
        !fields.name ||
        !fields.price ||
        !fields.description ||
        !fields.collectionId
      ) {
        throw new CustomError("Please fill all details", 500);
      }

      // handling images
      let imgArrayResp = Promise.all(
        Object.keys(files).map(async (filekey, index) => {
          const element = files[filekey];

          console.log(`line 50 ${element.filepath} `)
          console.log(typeof(element))
        
          const data = fs.readFileSync(element.filepath);

          console.log("line 62", data);

        //   console.log(typeof(s3FileUpload))
          const upload = await s3FileUpload({
            bucketName: config.S3_BUCKET_NAME,
            key: `products/${productId}/photo_${index + 1}.png`,
            body: data,
            contentType: element.mimetype,
          });
          return {
            secure_url: upload.Location,
          };
        })
      );

      let imgArray = await imgArrayResp;

      const product = await Product.create({
        _id: productId,
        photos: imgArray,
        ...fields,
      });

      if (!product) {
        throw new CustomError("Product was not created", 400);
        //remove image
      }
      res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
        product,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      return res.status(500).json({
        success: false,
        message: error.message || "Something went wrong",
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```
 let imgArrayResp = Promise.all(
        Object.keys(files).map(async (filekey, index) => {
          const element = files[filekey];

          console.log(`line 50 ${element.filepath} `)
          console.log(typeof(element))
        
          const data = fs.readFileSync(element.filepath);

          console.log("line 62", data);

        //   console.log(typeof(s3FileUpload))
          const upload = await s3FileUpload({
            bucketName: config.S3_BUCKET_NAME,
            key: `products/${productId}/photo_${index + 1}.png`,
            body: data,
            contentType: element.mimetype,
          });
          return {
            secure_url: upload.Location,
          };
        })
      );
```

i tried to cosole the element's type its in object . i think element.filepath is not accesable

Answer (score 0):

```
const element = files[filekey][0];
```

Maybe element was an array